# How do I close the first window when the next one opens?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Xcode 9.2, macOS 10.12.6, Swift 4. I don't really know what I'm doing, so please explain what to do in detail.

I am trying to make it so that the first window is closed when the second one is opened. The button`CONTINUE` makes the second window open, via show segue.
[image: img1]
I followed the Control+Click and drag as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089024/swift-make-button-trigger-segue-to-new-scene), and tried to make the CONTINUE button close the first window when closed in two different ways; with `self.view.window?.close()` and with setting the key equivalent to `CMD`+`W`.[image: img2]

I've tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096257/os-x-storyboards-using-show-segue-without-allowing-duplicate-new-windows-to-s), but that did not solve my problem.

Edit:

---

I have two windows, one each goes to the other one. Here is the code:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueToWIR" {
            view.window?.close()
        }
        //neither if or else if make this work
        if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueToWarning" {
            view.window?.close()
        }
    }
```

The second if statement doesn't cause an error, but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X storyboards: using "show" segue without allowing duplicate new windows to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096257/os-x-storyboards-using-show-segue-without-allowing-duplicate-new-windows-to-s)

Comment: @ChrisZielinski That solution didn't work, thanks for suggesting it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike UIKit's `UIControl`, AppKit only permits a single target-action per `NSControl` instance. You are attempting to use two:

1. The *show* segue.
2. The action method connection you created using the <kbd>control</kbd> + click & drag method.

The segue takes precedence. You can verify this by setting a breakpoint at `CONTINUE(_:)`. You'll find that the action method never gets called!

So scrap the action method &, alternatively, use:

> **Note:** The below implementation is valid for Swift 4.2+.

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    // Note: For Swift 4, replace `segue.identifier` with `segue.identifier?.rawValue`.
    if segue.identifier == "my-segue-identifier" {
        view.window?.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode changes `if segue.identifier` to `if segue.identifier!.rawValue`, which works, so would you mind editing your answer to reflect this?

Comment: Apparently I can't use this twice, I'm told `'prepare(for:sender:)' has already been overridden`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Also, adding another `if segue.identifier!.rawValue == "SegueName" {
            view.window?.close()` after the existing one doesn't cause the window to close

Comment: Well you must’ve overridden it somewhere... You can’t have two identical method declarations within the same scope. & I don’t understand your other comment.

Comment: I'll add it to my question

Comment: If you set a breakpoint inside the second `if` statement, does it ever halt? Is the other segue also a _show_ segue?